# How to test the console.log output of a function to see if it contains or doesn't contain a string?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a function which logs errors, and details about the error object. In non-prod it outputs a stack trace. In prod it's not supposed to output a stack trace. It determines prod or non-prod based on `process.env.STAGE`. This has been confirmed to be working as expected.

I'd like to create a test in Jest to validate this. Based on what I researched I think the following is supposed to work. However, both test cases always pass even though one has a `.not`; so something isn't working right.

What am I doing wrong?

```
describe('Validate util.logData', ()=>{
    const log = console.log; // save original console.log function

    beforeEach(async () => {
        console.log = jest.fn(); // create a new mock function for each test
    });
    afterAll(() => {
        console.log = log; // restore original console.log after all tests
    });
    test('Validate util.logData will not output a stack trace in Prod. This should pass.', ()=>{
        process.env.STAGE='PROD'
        util.logData('JestTest', new Error('Jest Test'),['BETA', 'PROD']).then(()=>{
            expect(console.log).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.stringContaining('Error: Jest Test'));
        });
    });
    test('Validate util.logData will output a stack trace in Prod. This should fail.', ()=>{
        process.env.STAGE='PROD'
        util.logData('JestTest', new Error('Jest Test'),['BETA', 'PROD']).then(()=>{
            expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.stringContaining('Error: Jest Test'));
        });
    });
})
```

The function:

```
exports.logData = function(caller, toLog,logEnv=['LOCAL', 'GAMMA']){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        try{
            let message = "";
            const env = (process.env.STAGE) ? process.env.STAGE : 'LOCAL';
            logEnv = (Array.isArray(logEnv) && (typeof logEnv[0] === 'string' || logEnv[0] instanceof String))
                ?  logEnv.map(i=>i.toUpperCase()) : ['LOCAL', 'GAMMA'];
            if(logEnv.includes(env.toUpperCase())){
                if (typeof toLog === 'string' || toLog instanceof String) {
                    message = toLog;
                } else {
                    if(toLog.message) {
                        message += toLog.message;
                    }
                    if(env.toUpperCase() !== 'PROD') {
                        if (toLog.stack) {
                            message += "\n\t" + toLog.stack;
                        }
                        message += "\n\t" + JSON.stringify(toLog, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(toLog));
                    }
                }
                if(message !== ''){
                    const output = (new Date()).toUTCString() + " - " + caller + " - " + message
                    console.log(output);
                    resolve(output);
                }
            }
        } catch(error){
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: First things first you need to await or return the promise, so that the expectation actually happens _during the test_: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank-you! That resolved the original issue if you'd like to post it as an answer. I'm now seeing one pass and one fail.

With that said, I still have one small problem. Rather than Jest looking at ALL the console.log entries from util.logData, it appears to only be looking at the last logData. Do you know if there is a way to have it look at all of the console.log's from that function?

Comment: Show the code of the `util.logData`. We can't help without seeing the code under test. I think that's why you got a down-vote. I am not the downvoter.

Comment: @LinDu Thank-you. This is fixed. I didn't think the function mattered, just that it was outputting console.log, but clearly that's not the case. Thanks for pointing out what is missing.

Answer (score -1):

The way I was calling the code the mock was not listening when the output was sent to console log. If someone else can give a better and more detailed explanation, I will accept their answer over mine; but the following is ultimately what worked for me:

```
describe('Validate util.logData', ()=>{
    test('Validate util.logData will not output a stack trace in Prod', async ()=>{
        const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation(() => { });
        process.env.STAGE='PROD';
        await util.logData('JestTest', new Error('Jest Test'),['BETA', 'PROD']);
        expect(logSpy.mock.lastCall[0]).not.toContain('Error: Jest Test');
        logSpy.mockRestore();
    });
    test('Validate util.logData will  output a stack trace in non-Prod', async ()=>{
        const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation(() => { });
        process.env.STAGE='BETA';
        await util.logData('JestTest', new Error('Jest Test'),['BETA', 'PROD']);
        expect(logSpy.mock.lastCall[0]).toContain('Error: Jest Test');
        logSpy.mockRestore();
    });
});
```